# The CookieManager of setCookie method is not work on iphone iPhone x 12.2 for the flutter_inappbrowser,thanks

Tags: iphone, inappbrowser, setcookie

Help me, please! The `CookieManager` of `setCookie` method is not work on iPhone x 12.2, thanks!

```
child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: index_url,
                initialHeaders: {},
                initialOptions: {},
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  _webViewController = controller;
                  //去商品详情
                  _webViewController
                      .addJavaScriptHandler('flutter_toGoodDetailAct', (args) {
                    print("收到来自web的消息 flutter_toGoodDetailAct-->" +
                        args.toString());
                    var arg = args[0];
                    if (arg == null) {
                      return;
                    }
                    flutter_toGoodDetailAct(arg);
                  });
```

Comment: Any answer for this?